# custom-header not working

Tags: php

I have set the add_theme_support('custom-header', $defaults); in the functions.php file. It shows up in the customiser but when I add an image it does not appear in the preview or the live site.

My code is:

```
$defaults = array(

'height'                 => 250,
'header-text'            => true,
'uploads'                => true,
'video'                  => true
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $defaults );
```

The height of 250 does show up as a space is etched out for the image to be added but the image itself won't appear when uploaded. Also the cropping of the image doesn't work, it just displays a dark image, I hit crop and it saves as is, could that be the issue? It's not saving right?

The same thing happens for a video, it shows up in the customiser to add the video but it does not appear in the preview or the site.

Comment: `add_theme_support()` is only step one. You still need to actually output it into your template: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/custom-headers/#displaying-custom-header

Comment: Ok I've added the get_header_image() code that is in that link along with adding a height argument to the add_theme_support() $defaults variable. The cropping is now working but it's still not showing up on the site.

Comment: Got it working. The code need to be within the <header> tags rather than simply a div with an id of site-header. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Add your solution as answer, you can accept your own answer. Or you might consider deleting your question. Thanks.

Comment: Ah ok. Will create a comment, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. I had to call the function in my page where I want it to work, the method of doing so is here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/custom-headers/#displaying-custom-header (link provided by Jacob Peattie) and it needs to be within the  tags rather than simply a div with an id of site-header.